# Drupal 9 disable cache page with query string

Tags: caching, drupal, drupal-9

I have Drupal 9.
I want to disable cache when query string exists.

This is my code:

```
function mytheme_preprocess_page(&$variables)
{
  
  if(isset($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'])) {


    if(!empty($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']))
    {

      \Drupal::service('page_cache_kill_switch')->trigger();
    }


  }
}
```

I checked that the table "cache_data" still has new rows with different query string (/pagina-esempio?a=x).
I tried with drupal 8 and i remember that rows not inserted.

[image]

Maybe i miss something about cache.
How can i avoid new rows in this table?

Comment: I think the kill switch need to be called _earlier_ in the handling of the request, because here in a theme preprocess hook the rendering process has already begun. Instead, you can subscribe to `KernelEvents::REQUEST` and define a specific handler.

Comment: Ok, so i have to learn how to make a listener in drupal.

Comment: I created a listener but still not working, i have new rows in table.